# how to implement 3D image manipulation using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

i want to implement 3D image manipulation(i.e., image edit,re-size,**rotate**,zoom-in & zoom-out).
please give me your ideas as soon as possible.

Comment: Its a good question.  However expressions such as "please give me your ideas as soon as possible."  are not welcome.  It implies that your question is of greater import than others.  SO has the fastest answer speed on the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 2.0 does not support true 3D. Silverlight 3 will support a perspective projection simulated 3D (think 3D images in PowerPoint).

For standard image manipulation you have a few ways to go. If you just want to do rotation and resizing for *display* purposes, you can set a RenderTransform on the image object. This does not actually change the bits in the image but just cases them to be drawn differently.

If you want to learn about full image processing, see this other post on StackOverflow:

[Image Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120/image-processing-in-silverlight-2)