# image zoom with slider

Tags: silverlight-3.0

How can I do zooming picture with a slider

Comment: See this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120/image-processing-in-silverlight-2

Answer (score 1):

split your problem into two

zoom: http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/24/deep-zoom-zooming-and-panning-images-using-silverlight-seadragon.aspx

slider: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Slider02262009163833PM/Slider.aspx